# Bean validation is not working spring data neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using SDN with embedded neo4j. i have to use bean validate, but it not working.null is saving in database without any exception.

Dependency is

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.2.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.1.Final'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA'      
}

xml config is 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="neo4j"></context:component-scan>
<neo4j:config
storeDirectory="target/db2"
base-package="neo4j"/>

<bean id="validator"
class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

<neo4j:repositories base-package="neo4j" />
</beans>
```

entity class

```
@NodeEntity
class Role {
    @GraphId Long graphId

    @NotNull
    String name;

}
```

controller is

```
@Transactional
    def saveUser(){

        println "in saveUser"
        Role role = new Role();
        Neo4jTemplate.save(role);

    }
```

I am using spring-data-neo4j 3.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: is it using the right annotation from the validations-api?

Comment: yes, i have imported    javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

Comment: Can you test another constraint like NotEmpty or Max or so?

Comment: yes i tried max validation,still not working

Comment: i tried even this one org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty; but not sucessfull. i am building a grails application, is there any issue with it ?

Comment: @PrabjotSingh Could you please mark the answer as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

**Spring Data Neo4j 6.x** (the one you use importing spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.x) **removed the possibility of creating constraints directly from the domain model**.

Now, this means you have to use Neo4j's Cypher query language and execute what you want to do (e.g.: `CREATE CONSTRAINT notnull_name IF NOT EXISTS ON (role:Role) ASSERT EXISTS (role.name)` ).

Obviously, this is hard to manage, since you'd have to execute a script before your application starts. And it is difficult for production environments.

**So [Liquigraph](https://www.liquigraph.org/4.x/index.html) has been created: it is a tool that executes, for us, scripts.**

The mechanism is the following and I report this [issue](https://github.com/liquibase/liquigraph/issues/433) on Github that explains everything well.

---

### Solution

**Pom.xml dependencies**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquigraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquigraph-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**changelog.xml file** (located here -> {project_dir}/src/main/resources/db/liquigraph/changelog.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<changelog xmlns="http://www.liquigraph.org/schema/1.0/liquigraph.xsd">
    <changeset id="constraints" author="you">
        <query>CREATE CONSTRAINT notnull_name IF NOT EXISTS ON (role:Role) ASSERT EXISTS (role.name)</query>
    </changeset>
</changelog>
```

**application.yml properties**:

```
spring:
  neo4j:
    uri: neo4j://localhost:7687                           #neo4j+s if you use an HTTPS Neo4j instance
    authentication:
      username: neo4j
      password: neo4j
  datasource:                                             #Liquigraph configuration used by Liquigraph POM dependency
    url: jdbc:neo4j:neo4j://localhost?encryption=false    #encryption=true if you use an HTTPS Neo4j instance
    driver-class-name: org.neo4j.jdbc.boltrouting.BoltRoutingNeo4jDriver
    username: neo4j
    password: neo4j
```

---

✔️ ## At the startup, the following constraints will be created ##

**Specific Logs**:

```
2021-01-12 18:33:18.917  INFO 2420 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-12 18:33:18.940  INFO 2420 --- [           main] Driver                                   : Routing driver instance 706067443 created for server address localhost:7687
2021-01-12 18:33:21.510  INFO 2420 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-01-12 18:33:22.672  INFO 2420 --- [           main] o.l.core.io.ChangelogGraphWriter         : Executing postcondition of changeset ID constraints by you
2021-01-12 18:33:22.775  INFO 2420 --- [           main] o.l.core.io.ChangelogGraphWriter         : Changeset ID constraints by you was just executed
```

As you can see, your  into changelog.xml has been applied ✔️.

Comment: how can i do this using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j? should i still just pull in all 3 of these dependencies on top?

Comment: @DanielJeney yes! I am using that very dependency; then, I applied these other 3 on top :)